# Facebook sharer: can I change the description after it has been shared?

Tags: facebook

I use the Facebook share button on a website I developed.

Just after the website went live, someone shared the homepage while the value for og:title was still set to "under construction".

Now, the og:title is set to a more appropriate value and the sharer preview displays the correct title when I want to share the homepage. BUT the actual title used on the wall (or message) is "under contruction".

Can anyone tell me how (or if) I can reset that?

Comment: Thank lgy. Using the Facebook debug tool resetted the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Run the URL through the [Facebook Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) which will clear the cache for your page